# How to use MatchIT R package to use caliper width on logit of the propensity score instead of the propensity score?

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

The R package MatchIT uses a caliper width on the standard deviation of the propensity score. Is there a way to use logit of the propensity score?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In the `link` argument, specifiy `link = "linear.logit"`. Below is an example:

```r
m <- matchit(A ~ X1 + X2, data = data, method = "nearest",
             distance = "glm", link = "linear.logit",
             caliper = .2)
```

This does nearest neighbor matching on the logit of the propensity score with a caliper of .2 standard deviations of the logit of the propensity score.

Comment: Thanks. I also have another question regarding calculation of weights when using caliper and say matching ratio of 1:2. What is the idea behind new stratum "propensity score"? Is it because because some treated observations may not get two matches from the control. So in order to adjust that is the weight calculated using new stratum "propensity score"? I understand the calculation behind the weights but just wanted to get an idea.

Comment: What is the default link option in matchit function?

Comment: The default link is `"logit"` for a logistic regression propensity score. The stratum PS method for calculating matching weights works no matter how the strata are formed, e.g., full matching, CEM, or k:1 matching. It's not the only way to describe how the weights are calculated for k:1 matching, which is a simpler scenario, but I just use a single method of calculation to keep things simple from the programming side. Feel free to ask a question on CV if you want me to go into more detail.

Comment: What is the difference between setting std.caliper = TRUE and using link = "linear.logit" ? What if use both ?

Comment: @GuillaumeL they are unrelated. Using `std.caliper = TRUE` means that whatever value is supplied to `caliper` is in standard deviation units. Using `link = "linear.logit"` means that matching is done on the logit of the PS, and if a caliper is used, it is used on the logit of the PS.

Comment: Isn't `std.caliper=TRUE` a default option?

Comment: Yes, so the caliper is by default in SD units. But is it in SD units of the propensity score or of the logit of the propensity score? That is controlled by the `link` argument. Similarly, if you set `std.caliper = FALSE`, now the caliper is in raw units. But is it raw units of the propensity score or of the logit of the propensity score? Again, that is controlled by the `link` argument.